# Can't edit "Gmail SMTP Server" on iOS 10.3.1

Tags: iphone, ios, gmail

I'm having problems recently with sending email from my gmail account on my iPhone using the mail app (keep being told username or password is incorrect, when they definitely are not).  In trying to troubleshoot, I wanted to edit my SMTP server settings, but there is only one "Primary Server" shown and when I tap it to edit (it has no username or password so I wanted to manually add them in), everything is greyed out, and nothing can be edited.  Not only that, but I can't even turn it off because when I flip the switch to deactivate it, there is no way to "save" the change, and as soon as I back out of that page in any way, the change is lost and the server remains activated.

How can I edit this SMTP server's settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm really not sure why this changed anything, but I logged out of my Google account from my desktop browser, then logged back in.  Immediately after so doing, I sent a new email on my phone from my GMail account, and it worked perfectly fine, without a hitch.  Go figure!

Answer (score -1):

To Add new SMTP servers in iOS Mail:

1. Settings > Mail, Contract, Calendars > Tap your Gmail account. Tap
   Account.
2. Under the heading "Outgoing Mail Server", tap SMTP.
3. Under the heading "Other SMPT Server", tap Add Server...

You can enter the host name, username and password

Comment: Thanks but I'm not looking to add a new server (though I already tried it anyway to no avail).  My question was how to edit the Primary Server already entered into iOS.